# Whenever I froth my milk and pour it into the espresso, it dries and makes water under it. How do I fix that?

Tags: milk, steamed-milk, foamed-milk

So I'm learning how to make coffee and I absolutely love it but the hardest part about it is steaming the milk. Whenever I make a latte or a capp the foam sort of rises and makes this layer of froth and but I want the froth fully in the espresso. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Just for clarification: you want *only foam* and think liquid milk is somehow wrong?

Comment: No Im asking whenever I serve Lattes or capps the froth usually rises to the top and leaves water and espresso under the froth. Im told that this is wrong and Im frothing the milk wrong

Comment: Could we perhaps get a picture? Ideally in a glass, so that we can see what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following comment:

> No Im asking whenever I serve Lattes or capps the froth usually rises to the top and leaves water and espresso under the froth. Im told that this is wrong and Im frothing the milk wrong

I surmise that you're using a steam pipe and you're frothing the entire drink with the espresso already in the cup. The problem you're experiencing (as I understand it) is that you don't get a nice emulsion, you get some water from the steam at the bottom.

Based on that, I'd recommend the following:

- Froth the milk separately, for example in a metal frothing jug. Add it to the espresso after frothing.
- Use cold milk, this froths better.
- When steaming the milk, your technique is very important. Specifically, you want the tip of the steam wand to be just below the surface of the milk. (This isn't important if you have a special steam wand which also blows in air.)